# Checking size of stack (ArrayList) in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, bluej

I'm trying to implement a stack with an Array List.
BlueJ tells me that "size" has private access in java.util.ArrayList even though the Array List is public, when I'm compiling.

```
int stackLength = stackStorage.size;
System.out.println(+stackLength);
```

And if I change the line to..

```
int stackLength = stackStorage.size();
```

the program compiles and I get a nullPointerExcetion when I run the function.

I don't understand why this is happening because a value cannot be manually assigned because the value needs to come from the stack size.

Any help appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Your stackStorage is null.

Comment: Hi, just updating whether the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly call for the variable *(because it's a private field)*. You should use `stackStorage.size()` instead. Also make sure stackStorage is actually instantiated.

---

You most probably have:

```
ArrayList<Object> stackStorage;
```

However you must instantiate it somewhere like so:

```
stackStorage = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

This may also be done on the same line:

```
ArrayList<Object> stackStorage = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Once you have created this `ArrayList` do note that it still doesn't have any elements in it. In order to actually add an `Integer` to the array simply do:

```
stackStorage.add(number);
```

And after you do that, if you call `stackStorage.size()` it should return 1, meaning there's one element in the `ArrayList`. If you wish to add more, simply use the `add()` method. Also make sure you add the same object as you instantiated it with. You can't store `String` in `ArrayList<Integer>` for example.

**Full-code example:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> stackStorage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
stackStorage.add(10); //Now has value `10` in `index[0]`
System.out.println("index[0]: " + stackStorage.get(0)); //Prints 10
System.out.println("stackStorage.size() = " + stackStorage.size()) //Prints 1
```

---

In your case replace `Object` with `Integer` if you wish to store integers. `NullPointerException` means your object is still `null` when you tried to call `size()`. This should solve your issue. If you're not sure what `null` is or don't quite understand what NPE(NullPointException) is I suggest reading about it and if you have further difficulties, posting it here.

Comment: It has been instantiated and the object is now changed to "Integer", but the value it outputs is always "0" once I've added to the stack

Comment: @ScottSummers - If this satisfies your question, please tick it as the correct answer. And also, welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

That's because `size` is a `private field` and hence you don't have access to it, where `size()` is a `public method` that you can use. Therefore call `size()` to get the size of the `ArrayList`. The `NullPointerException` has nothing to do with size  it is simple because your object is not initialized, make sure you initialize your objects before using them.

```
List<Something> list = new ArrayList<Something>();
```

Answer (score 0):

size is a private variable
size() is a public method
For getting the size of the arrayList , you need to use size() and before calling size() dont forgot to intialize the array List like below .

List list = new ArrayList();

Comment: That's not how you initialize an array.

Comment: Excuse me, meant to say `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Juxhin Well, you *can* initialize it that way .. you shouldn't since he uses raw types and they are bad, but you can.